# Add class to empty inputs

Tags: jquery, validation

I have the following code to search a form and detect empty inputs or unchecked boxes that we want to be compulsory. Unfortunately, this is adding the class .error to all elements with the class .required, even if they do contain content/have been checked.

How would this script be tweaked in order to only add .error to empty elements? Is this even the best approach for validation?

```
$("#step-1-next").click(function(){
    var empty = $("#step-1").find("input.required").filter(function() {
        return this.value === "";
    });
    if(empty.length || !$("input[name='food']:checked").val() || $("#bus_type").val() == "") {
        $("#step-1").find(".required").addClass('error');
    } else {
        // Do something else
    }
});
```

Comment: `empty.addClass('error')`

Comment: Can you setup a fiddle? I have had to use these checks a million times. The solution can be simpler if we can see the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$("#step-1-next").click(function(){
   $("#step-1").find("input.required").filter(function() {
   if( $(this).val().length === 0 ) {
     $(this).addClass("error");
   }
});
```

This should check all inputs that you specify and see if they have a value. If not it will add the error class.

Is it the best approach for validation? That depends on how secure you want your application to be. If I were using this code on a commerce  site I would implement additional checks to ensure that there are no XSS vulnerabilities and that your application is compliant with [PCI](https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/).

You can find examples [here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate/) for validations in pure Javascript.

This is a great jQuery [plugin](http://www.formvalidator.net/) that takes care of all your validations.

Comment: Thanks Larrydx, this works perfectly. Security, it's not for a commerce site, just a contact form, so I guess we should be ok.

Comment: Glad to help out. Please mark the answer as accepted if it works for you so that this question is no longer unanswered.